# pgfplots to plot a function from [4,4.001]

Tags: pgfplots

When I try to plot a function on a small range, the output is an empty graph from 0 to 1 on the x and y axis. What can I do to fix this? My tex looks like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=4.0,
xmax=4.001,
samples=60,
xlabel=$time$,
ylabel={$acceleration$}
] 

\addplot [very thick, blue] {5*x-x^2}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can rescale the calculation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
samples=60,
xlabel=$time$,
xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{4+\tick/1000}\pgfmathresult,
ylabel={$acceleration$}
] 

\addplot [very thick, blue] {5*(4+x/1000)-(4+x/1000)^2}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How does this line work?
    xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{4+\tick/1000}\pgfmathresult

Comment: @user2116192 as far as I understand it (which isn't far, I've never used tikz apart from the occasional answer here) `\pgfmathparse` is the general utility function in pgf to evaluate an expression, leaving its result in `\pgfmathresult` in this context `\tick` is the value going from 0 to 1 which would be the default label, but by setting the xticklable key it comes out as 4.00.. instead.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the library `fixedpointarithmetic`, which uses the `fp` package for calculations (9 digits before and 9 after the decimal point).

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that the function isn't evaluated within the axis range. The standard `domain` is `-5:5` (this is not changed by setting `xmin` and `xmax`), so with 60 samples, the function is evaluated at 3.98 and 4.15. If you set the `domain=4:4.001` (so equal to the visible range set using `xmin` and `xmax`), the data is plotted correctly without any manual coordinate transformations:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
compat=newest,
samples=60,
xmin=4.0, xmax=4.001,
domain=4:4.001,
xlabel=Time $t$,
ylabel=Acceleration $a$,
ticklabel style={ % Make sure all relevant digits are printed
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=4
}
] 

\addplot [very thick, blue] {5*x-x^2}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, instead of `$time$`/`$acceleration$` in the labels we should write `\textit{...}` if we want italic text or simply `...` if we want it upright. Not the math mode.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It shows that as $\Delta t$ shrinks to zero, the acceleration tends toward some value, which allows one to plot complicated motion with a few simple equations and a computer. Thanks again!