# Plotting data with small variations

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I have a set of data with small variations that I am trying to plot using `pfgplots`. I am currently using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$}
    ]
\addplot table {
    0 1.0000018
    1 1.0000056
    2 1.0000020
    3 1.0000071
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like the amplitude of the variation to be visible.

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114528/63689), but I would rather not have to rescale the calculation or set the minimal and maximal values "by hand", since I have several such plots with different ranges and different amplitudes.

The Python matplotlib.pyplot.plot function does this automatically and indicates `+1.0e0` at the top of the y axis. Is there a way of getting a similar result with pgf?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this seems to be beyond (La)TeX's numeric capabilities. But if you are willing to use LuaLaTeX you could do ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher
        % AND use LuaLaTeX to use PGFPlots lua capabilities
        compat=1.12,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % either show more digits of the numbers ...
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=7,
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%        % ... and/or shift the values by using the "scale" feature
%        scaled y ticks=manual:{$+1$}{%
%            \pgfmathparse{#1-1}%
%        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot table {
            0 1.0000018
            1 1.0000056
            2 1.0000020
            3 1.0000071
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]