# Plot a function between two values

Tags: pgfplots

This question is meant as a duplicate of the question: [pgfplots to plot a function from [4,4.001]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114528/pgfplots-to-plot-a-function-from-4-4-001)

I don't know if it's an acceptable idea (creating a question just to get a duplicate) but when searching for my question title, in the stack exchange search bar, nothing meaningful came up.

I point to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115422/125223)